# Android OnePlus phone, missing com.google.android.gsf package

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I recently got the new "1 plus" phone. it has `CyanogenMod 11` based on `Android 4.4.4`.

**It does not have any google app, so no Play Store nor Google Play Services nor any other service.**

I just need to confirm that the following error is due to those missing packages, and whether or not I'm able to fix it.

Here is the error thrown for GCM initiation:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: 
Device does not have package com.google.android.gsf
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that error is because of the missing services.

com.google.android.gsf - > (google services framework).

Here you can find the Google play services APK latest version 
http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-play-services/

Answer (score 1):

CM doesn't come with Gapps. See here: http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Google_Apps

Comment: This doesn't provide an answer to the question. This post should be a comment under the question, to post comments wait until you get enough reputation.