# Device does not have package com.google.android.gsf in push notification

Tags: android, push-notification

I have some issue in push notification. I run my app on real device but its thrown an exception `device does not have package com.google.android.gsf` . I import gcm.jar and build class path.

please help me i am new in android developing.

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28566360/android-oneplus-phone-missing-com-google-android-gsf-package

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11339445/com-google-android-gsf-package-couldnt-be-found

Comment: I see but it i couldn't find right answer.